# Multiple lists inside a list nested for certain conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am solving a problem from [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/py-collections-ordereddict) that requires collections.ordereddict() to be used. In the program, I am supposed to take a bunch of input and store it in the ordereddict, sum the values of the duplicate items and represent it in order.
So for the first part, I wrote the following code which probably isn't the problem here..

```
ordi = OrderedDict()
N = int(input())
for i in range(N):
    item_info = input().split()
    if (len(item_info)>2):
        item_name = str(item_info[0]+" "+item_info[1])
        price = item_info[-1]
    else:
        item_name= str(item_info[0])
        price = item_info[-1]
    if item_name not in ordi:
        ordi[item_name]= price
    else:
        ordi[item_name]=[ordi[item_name]]
        ordi[item_name].append(price)
# print(ordi)

Test input given by hackerrank is:

9
BANANA FRIES 12
POTATO CHIPS 30
APPLE JUICE 10
CANDY 5
APPLE JUICE 10
CANDY 5
CANDY 5
CANDY 5
POTATO CHIPS 30
```

the next part of the code loops through the dictionary and is supposed to give the output sum in order

```
for keys, values in ordi.items():
    total = 0
    if isinstance(values, list):
        print(f"this is what's inside {keys} value ",values)
        int_vals = list(map(int, values))
        total = sum(int_vals)
        print(keys, total)
    else:
        print(keys,values)
```

This works for input that has two worded strings but doesn't work for one-worded strings i.e. Candy in this case. Now to debug what's inside of the value of candy key I printed it's values:

```
OUTPUT:
BANANA FRIES 12
this is what's inside POTATO CHIPS value  ['30', '30']
POTATO CHIPS 60
this is what's inside APPLE JUICE value  ['10', '10']
APPLE JUICE 20
this is what's inside CANDY value  [[['5', '5'], '5'], '5']
```

As you can see, inside of the candy value, there is lists of lists inside of a list which is uncalled for, I can't understand what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

```
ordi = OrderedDict()

N = int(input())
for i in range(N):
    item_info = input().split()
    
    item_name = " ".join(item_info[:-1])
    price = int(item_info[-1])

    if item_name not in ordi.keys():
        ordi[item_name] = price
    else:
        ordi[item_name] += price

print(ordi)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('BANANA FRIES', 12), ('POTATO CHIPS', 60), ('APPLE JUICE', 20), ('CANDY', 20)])
```

I submit it in hackerrank and it passed the tests, I don't exactly know what was the problem with your code, but I think it has something to do with the way you handled adding the values to the dict,
this part:

```
    if item_name not in ordi:
        ordi[item_name]= price
    else:
        ordi[item_name]=[ordi[item_name]]
        ordi[item_name].append(price)
```

I hope my solution will help you learn something new

if you want your code to work just do this:

```
    if item_name not in ordi.keys():
        ordi[item_name] = list(price)
    else:
        ordi[item_name].append(price)
```

The problem was with this part: `[ordi[item_name]]` if the item was a list you warped it in another list, and since the "CANDY" key had the most inputs he was problematic, not because the key was one word.
When I enter custom input with a lot of `POTATO CHIPS` this is what I get:

```
this is what's inside BANANA FRIES value  ['12', '12']
BANANA FRIES 24
this is what's inside POTATO CHIPS value  [[['30', '30'], '30'], '30']
```

Comment: Hey @omercotkd, thank you for your solution and also for pointing out where it went wrong in my code, however, my program still isn't generating the output that was supposed to come... it's printing out the list itself rather than the sum

Comment: I forgot to include the printing part, just do a for loop that prints the key-value pairs: `for key, item in ordi: print(key, item)` and if you are using your solution don't forget to  sum the list of values.